# Подсчет количества ip адресов в диапазоне IPv6?

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, ipv6

Дан IPv6 диапазон (разделитель дефис): `2c0f:ffd8::-2c0f:ffd8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`

Как быстро подсчитать колличество IP адресов в этом диапазоне?

Comment: Слово "быстро" лишнее. Или, давайте уточним: вы не собираетесь сканить все IP диапазона в поисках отвечающих устройств, а просто нужно подсчитать возможное число адресов, верно?

Comment: @AK, слово "быстро" - как раз не лишнее. Сканировать все IP адреса, которые содержит диапазон - не собираюсь. Нужно подсчитать только колл-во IP адресов, которое содержит диапазон. Подсчет прямым перебором, использовав тот же IEnumerator (под капотом которого обычный for и yield) или аналоги - очень долго (правда пока не пробовал распаралеливать вычисления, но судя по первоначальным данным - даже они будут выполняться долго).

Comment: Вариант: из конечного адреса вычесть начальный и прибавить один, не подходит? Или недостаточно быстро?

Comment: PowerShell: `function IPAddressAsBigInteger { param([IPAddress]$Addr) $Bytes = $Addr.GetAddressBytes(); [Array]::Reverse($Bytes); if($Bytes[-1] -ge 128) { [Array]::Resize([ref]$Bytes, $Bytes.Length+1) } [BigInt]$Bytes } $Begin, $End = '2c0f:ffd8::-2c0f:ffd8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff' -split '-'; (IPAddressAsBigInteger $End) - (IPAddressAsBigInteger $Begin) + 1`

Answer (score 6):

В диапазоне адресов специального формата, вроде того, который показан у вас в вопросе (общий префикс, и 00..00-ff...ff) количество адресов определяется очень просто. Берется количество доступных для изменения бит, и 2 возводится в эту степень.

Так, ваш префикс `2c0f:ffd8` содержит 8*4 = 32 бита, остается 96 изменяемых бит, что дает 2^96 = 79 228 162 514 264 337 593 543 950 336 разных адресов.

Answer (score 4):

Если не учитывать зарезервированные диапазоны адресов, то самый простой способ, как написал в комментах @PetSerAl, преобразовать оба адреса в числа и вычесть одно из другого.

IPv6 содержит 128 бит и его численное значение не влезет ни в `long`, ни в `decimal`, поэтому для расчетов потребуется использовать [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) (для этого нужно подключить `System.Numerics`).

Для преобразования сналала переведем адрес в массив байтов с помощью [`IPAddress.GetAddressBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes(v=vs.110).aspx), затем воспользуемся конструктором [`BigInteger(byte[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx).

При преобразовании нужно учесть различия в байтовом представлении:

- `IPAddress.GetAddressBytes` возвращает байты начиная со старших разрядов, а `BigInteger` ожидает получить их в обратном порядке, поэтому массив потребуется перевернуть;
- `BigInteger` рассматривает массив байтов как представление числа со знаком (число считается отрицательным если установлен старший бит старшего байта). Чтобы избежать этого можно добавить 0 в конец массива.

Пример метода, который преобразует строку адреса в число:

```
private static BigInteger AddressToBigInteger(string addressString)
{
    var address = IPAddress.Parse(addressString);
    var bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
    Array.Reverse(bytes);
    Array.Resize(ref bytes, bytes.Length+1); 
    return new BigInteger(bytes);
}
```

Применение:

```
var first = AddressToBigInteger("2c0f:ffd8::");
var second = AddressToBigInteger("2c0f:ffd8:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff");
Console.WriteLine(second - first + 1); //+1, чтобы включить обе границы диапазона
```

Comment: Сколько адресов в диапазоне `7fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff-8000::`?

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо за комментарий, исправил ошибку со знаковым битом. Теперь получается 2.